Cannot see the sphere created using Three.js and I have no clue why?
This is my first time working with three.js. I'm following a tutorial here. Even though I'm exactly following the tutorial, no sphere is appearing on the canvas. Here is my JavaScript code:
import * as THREE from "three";

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Create our sphere
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 64, 64); // radius, segment, segment
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: "#00ff83",
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);

// Light
const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
light.position.set(0, 10, 10);
scene.add(light);

// Adding the camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 800 / 600); // field of view, aspect ratio of 800x600
// Sphere and camera are at the same position. So, move back the camera a bit
camera.position.z = 20;
scene.add(camera);

// Renderer
const canvas = document.querySelector(".webgl");
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });

// Define how big out canvas is
renderer.setSize(800, 600);
renderer.render(scene, camera);

The corresponding HTML file is very simple and this is all it contains:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My First 3D website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>

    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

I tried multiple combinations of parameters passed to various functions but couldn't see anything on the screen. Couldn't find any help online.

Any errors in the console?

The unit of PointLight.intensity is candela (cd) and a value of 1 is way too low in order to illuminate your scene. Try it with 100 instead.
Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/o3vLeuq9/

I checked his code in my template, it works fine. Has to be something else in his config.

With latest three.js releases the OP's light intensity is definitely too low.

You right, I updated stuff, and works.
